# Get RSS feed after published date in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, filter, rss, rss-reader

I  am using below code for fetching all RSS feed and its working fine but i want to add filter for RSS feed that is fetch only those feed after mentioned published date. for example if i set day before yesterday date then fetch after day before yesterday date published feed.

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', $request_url, [
    'headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/xml'],
    'timeout' => 120
])->getBody()->getContents();

$responseXml = simplexml_load_string($response);
if ($responseXml instanceof \SimpleXMLElement)
{
        $key_value = (string)$responseXml->key_name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

RSS feeds are just XML documents so there's not any way to filter them in the request itself, unless the endpoint itself implements something like that.

If you want to filter the result in the context of a Laravel application, you should convert the result into a Laravel collection. You can then use the [filter](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-filter) method on the collection to filter out those items that have a date prior to the cutoff point. Alternatively, you can use [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to do the same on an array.

I would also add that parsing an RSS feed manually is more trouble than it's worth and you should consider switching to a library that will handle it more consistently and return proper response objects. Laminas Feed, for example, includes an excellent RSS reader class.